# How to return a sum of 0 for SQL Server case with no match

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that sums sales into case buckets, which works great, except that ***I need it to return 0 for buckets that have no sales***.

This is for MS SQL Server 2016, i've searched and found some similar issues that recommended using Coalesce, but i can't figure out how to apply that to my query.

The table data looks like this:
surveyid, projid, surveyperiod, quartersold, averagebaseprice2
65374, 12079, 2018-12-01, 4, 301805
70641, 10366, 2018-12-01, 9, 584390
etc

```
select t.range, sum(s.quartersold) as qtrsold, surveydate
from (
  select concat(datepart(quarter,surveyperiod), datepart(year,surveyperiod)) as surveydate, quartersold, case
   when averagebaseprice2 between 0 and 199999.99 then 'Less than $200,000'
   when averagebaseprice2 between 200000 and 224999.99 then '$200,000 - $224,000'
   when averagebaseprice2 between 225000 and 249999.99 then '$225,000 - $249,999'
   when averagebaseprice2 between 250000 and 274999.99 then '$250,000 - $274,999'
   when averagebaseprice2 between 275000 and 299999.99 then '$275,000 - $299,999'
   when averagebaseprice2 between 300000 and 324999.99 then '$300,000 - $324,999'
   when averagebaseprice2 between 325000 and 349999.99 then '$325,000 - $349,999'
   when averagebaseprice2 between 350000 and 374999.99 then '$350,000 - $374,999'
   when averagebaseprice2 between 375000 and 399999.99 then '$375,000 - $399,999'
   when averagebaseprice2 between 400000 and 424999.99 then '$400,000 - $424,999'
   when averagebaseprice2 between 425000 and 449999.99 then '$425,000 - $449,999'
   when averagebaseprice2 between 450000 and 474999.99 then '$450,000 - $474,999'
   when averagebaseprice2 between 475000 and 499999.99 then '$475,000 - $499,999'
   when averagebaseprice2 between 500000 and 599999.99 then '$500,000 - $599,999'
   when averagebaseprice2 between 600000 and 699999.99 then '$600,000 - $699,999'
   when averagebaseprice2 between 700000 and 799999.99 then '$700,000 - $799,999'
   when averagebaseprice2 between 800000 and 899999.99 then '$800,000 - $899,999'
   when averagebaseprice2 between 900000 and 999999999.99 then '$900,000 and greater'
   end as range
  from surveys s
  where datepart(year,s.surveyperiod) = 2018 
) t
group by t.range, surveydate
```

(Sorry i can't figure out how to format this better)
with the above query i'm getting:
        range                 qtrsold   surveydate
    $250,000 - $274,999 8   12018
    $275,000 - $299,999 8   12018
    $300,000 - $324,999 59  12018
    $325,000 - $349,999 22  12018
    $350,000 - $374,999 139 12018
    $375,000 - $399,999 82  12018
    $400,000 - $424,999 103 12018
    $425,000 - $449,999 92  12018
    $450,000 - $474,999 142 12018
    $475,000 - $499,999 144 12018
    $500,000 - $599,999 314 12018
    $600,000 - $699,999 64  12018
    $700,000 - $799,999 80  12018
    $800,000 - $899,999 18  12018
    $900,000 and greater    6   12018

i'd like to get:
    range                 qtrsold   surveydate
        **Less than $200,000      0       12018

        $200,000 - $224,000     0       12018

        $225,000 - $249,999     0       12018**
    $250,000 - $274,999 8   12018
    $275,000 - $299,999 8   12018
    $300,000 - $324,999 59  12018
    $325,000 - $349,999 22  12018
    $350,000 - $374,999 139 12018
    $375,000 - $399,999 82  12018
    $400,000 - $424,999 103 12018
    $425,000 - $449,999 92  12018
    $450,000 - $474,999 142 12018
    $475,000 - $499,999 144 12018
    $500,000 - $599,999 314 12018
    $600,000 - $699,999 64  12018
    $700,000 - $799,999 80  12018
    $800,000 - $899,999 18  12018
    $900,000 and greater    6   12018

Thank you very much for any assistance.

Comment: Can you provide more information around what the data looks like in the two tables?  I would imagine this could be solved by either converting to an outer join or unioning some dummy rows of data into the mix.

Comment: thanks Chad, i was just adding some sample data =]  there aren't any missing records because of the join .

Comment: i removed the join from the query, its just so i can limit results by region which is in a different table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate the ranges separately, and then use `left join` to bring in the data.  It is unclear where the columns are coming from, so the following is a guess:

```
select (datename(quarter, s.surveyperiod) + datename(year, s.surveyperiod)) as surveydate,
       v.range,
       coalesce(sum(?.quartersold), 0) as qtrsold
from (values ('Less than $200,000', 0 200000),
             ('$200,000 - $224,000', 0, 225,000),
             ('$225,000 - $249,999', 225000, 250000),
             . . .
     ) v(range, lo, hi) left join
     surveys s 
     on s. averagebaseprice2 >= v.lo and s.averagebaseprice2 < v.hi left join
     projects p
     on s.projid = p.projid
where s.surveyperiod >= '2018-01-01' and s.surveyperiod < '2019-01-01'
group by (datename(quarter, s.surveyperiod) + datename(year, s.surveyperiod)) as surveydate,
         v.range  ;
```

Comment: thanks very much Gordon, i appreciate your time.  i'm a bit confused by the values section, should the 2nd line read 200,000, 225,000? Also, sorry i'm not very good at writing queries, i forgot to add the s. in front of quartersold

Comment: i'm getting a incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'
select (datename(quarter, s.surveyperiod) + datename(year, s.surveyperiod)) as surveydate,v.range,coalesce(sum(s.quartersold), 0) as qtrsold
from (values ('Less than $200,000', 0, 200000),
 ('$200,000 - $224,000', 200000, 225000),
 ('$225,000 - $249,999', 225000, 250000)
 ) v(range, lo, hi) left join

Comment: surveys s on s.averagebaseprice2 >= v.lo and s.averagebaseprice2 < v.hi left join
projects p on s.projid = p.projid
where s.surveyperiod >= '2018-01-01' and s.surveyperiod < '2019-01-01'
group by (datename(quarter, s.surveyperiod) + datename(year, s.surveyperiod)) as surveydate, v.range

Comment: Thank you i was able to get it to work with my data, thanks a lot!